# Child Component is not updating whenever i set the state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Actually i want to update my child component

```
const callCoupon = async (promo) => {
     /// result = some api call;
     setpro(result);

}

const discountlist = pro.map(dis => 
            <DiscountGrid 
            key = {dis.id} 
            id = {dis.id}
            pname = {dis.pname}
            prdPrice = {dis.prdPrice}
            discountValue = {dis.discountValue}
            />);
```

when i click the button i used to call that function like this

```
const applyPromo = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    callCoupon(promo);
}
```

the above one is worked to child component

and another way to set the state is

```
React.useEffect(() => {
       preload(); 
         
    }, []);

const preload = async () => {
   const data = await some api call;
   callCoupon(data.discountId);
}
```

when preload function call the coupon function the child component not updated , i think its slow may be

please help me to overcome these things
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be its useful for some others

i just update the dependency of use effect with state length.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
       preload(); 
         
    }, [cart.length]); // cart is state
```

Thank you